# Print message before progress bar using tqdm

Tags: python, logging, tqdm

In my python project I'm using `tqdm` module to display a progress bar.
I want to print a persistent message on the line before the progress bar.

The `set_description` method prints the message on the same line, whilte `tqdm.write` creates a new line.

Using `set_description`

`$ python pbar.py
{Task_1 message} 3%|████         ]`

Is is possible to achieve this

`$ python pbar.py
{Task_1 message} 
3%|████         ]`

Edit:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

pbar = tqdm(m_list)
for item in m_list:
   # Do work
   pbar.update(1)
pbar.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple example with a loop:

```
import tqdm,time

for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(9),desc="{Task_1 message}"):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

final output:

```
{Task_1 message}: 100%|##############################################| 9/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.99it/s]
```

If you add `\n` to the description, it will trash your output like this:

```
{Task_1 message}
{Task_1 message}                                            | 0/9 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
{Task_1 message}                                    | 1/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.99it/s]
{Task_1 message}#                                   | 2/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.99it/s]
{Task_1 message}######                              | 3/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.99it/s]
{Task_1 message}###########                         | 4/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.99it/s]
{Task_1 message}################                    | 5/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.99it/s]
{Task_1 message}#####################               | 6/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.96it/s]
{Task_1 message}##########################          | 7/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.97it/s]
{Task_1 message}###############################     | 8/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.98it/s]
: 100%|#############################################| 9/9 [00:00<00:00,  9.98it/s]
```

The only thing you can do is to print the description first, and run the task without description, as you can only delete the current line in the terminal.

```
import tqdm,time

print("{Task_1 message}")
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(9)):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

As previously said, you can only delete the current line in the terminal (using `\r`), there are numerous topics about that limitation on SO.

The alternative is using curses, but that's a completely different approach.

Comment: There is an experimental plugin for tqdm to support multi line progress bars, but this is not production ready yet!

Answer (score 0):

This is a probable workaround which worked for me:

```
print("Your message", flush=True)
```